# Loading SCSS from npm packages in Node_Modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say I would like to use Material Design in my Vue APP and I would like to stick to the web component package distributed by Google. When I import the package in a `.vue` file:

```
@use '/node_modules/material-components-web/index.scss'
```

I get the following error

> Syntax Error: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
> ╷
> 28 │ @use '@material/feature-targeting/feature-targeting';
> │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

which I already know why! I think by default vue does not include node_modules in its web pack config and that's why it is trying to find the package at the root of the project and not the specified relative path.

Anyways, how can this be solved?

Comment: Try removing `/node_modules/` from your `@use` statement.

Comment: @code: no it doesn't solve it. As you see the error it has already read the index file, but couldn't resolve the dependency.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: @code: Yes I do, it's already there. It's a relative path problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use node_modules in paths in normal circumstances. If it doesn't work without it, this means it should be done in some other way. Here it's likely `@use '~material-components-web/index.scss'`

Comment: @EstusFlask: It really doesn't make any difference, it does not recognize node_modules

Comment: Btw, there's no "default vue". Is it Vue CLI? This should be stated. A possible solution also depends on your sass and sass loader version. No, the problem is not that it doesn't recognize node_modules. It doesn't recognize node modules without a tilde and expects `@material` to be relative folder. It would work if this were `~@material/...`. This requires `@material/` to be aliased to module path.